# Initialize constant from another constant with some changes

Tags: c

Let's say a have

```
struct table { int foo, bar, baz; };

static struct table const A = { .foo = 1, .bar = 2, .baz = 3 };
```

how could I declare `B` to be the exact same definition of `A` but with one change?

For instance what I would like to write is something like

```
static struct table const B = A, { .bar = 42 };
```

I am looking for a solution, if any, simpler than the following workaround:

```
#define A_DEFS .foo = 1, .bar = 2, .baz = 3
static struct table const A = { A_DEFS };

#define B_DEFS A_DEFS, .bar = 42
static struct table const B = { B_DEFS };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
static struct table const B = {  A.foo, .bar = 42, A.baz };
```

Comment: It is 'working', but in my real life case I have many fields, and many instances, it wouldn't be convenient having to repeat them every-time. But your answer let me come to a slightly better solution. I will answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

[SparKot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71275969/1141466) let me come to this slightly more convenient solution:

```
struct table { int foo, bar, baz; };
#define BASE(X) X.foo, X.bar, X.baz

static struct table const A = { .foo = 1, .bar = 2, .baz = 3 };
static struct table const B = { BASE(A), .bar = 42 };
static struct table const C = { BASE(B), .baz = 24 };
```